# Chrome (and possibly other browsers) caching my script include

Tags: javascript, caching, node.js, http-caching

PROBLEM:

I am hosting a widget on a client's website that will be different for each page on the site.

To render the widget, the client includes a script tag on their pages. This script tag is loaded for every page on the site and the code that it returns depends on the page.

So, if this script gets cached, the end result is that we serve a widget for the wrong page.

Right now, when we serve the script, we set in the response headers

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires : 24 hours in the past
```

yet sometimes browsers still cache the script.

QUESTION:

Is there a way to use http headers to stop caching in all cases or are we going to have to take a completely different approach?

UPDATE:

The headers that topek recommended greatly improved the non-cacheability of the scripts. However, (again in Chrome who seems to be the most cache-aggressive) when using the back, forward, or reload buttons the script is still cached. If you actually CLICK on anything it will be fetched from the server.

It seems that the only foolproof way to stop caching will be to set script sources that are guaranteed to be different for each page load (as suggested by esilija and tejs).

Comment: Why not just include a random query string parameter to the js url request? Or attach a datetime or something?

Comment: append a random meaningless query string.. like so: `script.js?14091341049134`. Generate the number from `+new Date`, which changes every millisecond.

Comment: We can do that if needed. However, we like the simplicity of only asking our clients to include a single script tag. I suppose we can ask them to include a few lines of js that would do what you suggest instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two headers should do the trick:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

or you set name according to the current page, e.g. when the user requests the page `http://domain/posts/1` then the script name could be `http://domain/script/scriptname/posts/1`. With approach the script would still be cachable per page.

Do not append a query string on the script like `script.js?random_string`. Proxies don't play well with this approach. If you want to place a random string in the name, then put it before `.js` like this `script-0934234234.js` and rewrite the request on your server.